# Transformation XSL/XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, xslt, transformation

The XSLTProcessor doesn't work in WebKit (Android): the include element in XSL are not managed.

So, I use Saxon to make a transformation XSL/XML. 
The problem is it so slow: the transformation last about one minute.

Have you an idea to make the transformation faster?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide some details on which version of Saxon (Saxon 6, Saxon 9, Saxon CE) you are trying to use and tell us how large the input is, provide a sample of the XSLT. Saxon 9 allows you to profile a stylesheet, see http://saxonica.com/documentation/html/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.html, that could be a starting point for further investigation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have Saxon CE 1.1. The XSLT is big: there are include in include in another include (more than 10 files in all). I try to test with Saxon 9 this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Large stylesheets can be a bit of a performance problem with Saxon-CE because of the need to fetch all the modules from the server and compile them before anything can be executed. Also it's much harder to get good instrumentation to see where exactly the time is going.

One approach to solving this is to see how much scope there is for cutting the stylesheet down to size or reducing the number of modules. Another approach is to do some of the processing on the server side, so the amount of transformation that needs to be done on the  browser side is reduced. Also these days there's a lot that can be done with CSS; don't use XSLT to do something that could be done with CSS.