# Merge XSL with include

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I must merge two xsl files into one:
The include element replaced by the content on the XSL file.

Do you know a software(or code) to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but you could simly transform your xslt stylesheet with a stylesheet that resolves the include.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:include">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)/*/*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I want to do this because Android doesn't understand include element in XSL with XSLTProcessor, cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989918/transformation-xsl-xml-in-android?noredirect=1#comment36968772_23989918. I tried to use a stylesheet like that, but there were two problems: 1) it wasn't recursive 2) the path of the include wasn't good: the first xsl call an include "common/xslt1.xsl" and xslt1 call another include "xslt2.xsl". The result was a xsl with an include "xslt2.xsl" but I would "common/xslt2.xsl" (the good folder). Thanks